# Send Text Message via Twilio in Python

Tags: python, twilio

I'm following this tutorial: [How to Send an SMS With Python Using Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/10/how-to-send-an-sms-with-python-using-twilio.html).

I've setup these variables as environment variables on my windows machine:

```
CELL_PHONE_NUMBER = +12015555555
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = my_twilio_account_sid
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = my_twilio_auth_token
TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER = +12016666666
```

This is my code:

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


account_sid = os.environ.get('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')
auth_token = os.environ.get('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

client.messages.create(from_=os.environ.get('TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER'),
                       to=os.environ.get('CELL_PHONE_NUMBER'),
                       body='You just sent an SMS from Python using Twilio!')
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sms.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.messages.create(from_=os.environ.get('TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER'),
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\message\__init__.py", line 86, in create
    payload = self._version.create(method='POST', uri=self._uri, data=data, )
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\twilio\base\version.py", line 209, in create
    raise self.exception(method, uri, response, 'Unable to create record')
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException:
[31m[49mHTTP Error[0m [37m[49mYour request was:[0m

[36m[49mPOST /Accounts/PN7afb27dc8e041f18dcf91fefe306ad34/Messages.json[0m

[37m[49mTwilio returned the following information:[0m

[34m[49mUnable to create record: Authentication Error - invalid username[0m

[37m[49mMore information may be available here:[0m

[34m[49mhttps://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003[0m
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003)

> **ERROR - 20003**
>   Permission Denied
>   You lack permission to the resource and method you requested.

Troubleshooting steps

> Verify the Account SID and Auth Token are correct
>   Verify the correct Account is being accessed
>   Ensure the Account is active, not suspended or closed
>   Ensure no extra characters or spaces are being included
>   Ensure JWT is only used with API Key

Try printing your `account_sid` and `auth_token` to double check they're correct, and verify that they match the ones on the twilio console